# Understanding type conversions in C while printing values

Tags: c

I have read about [type-casting in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm), including implicit, explicit typecasting as well as integer promotion.

But what's happening in the following statement,

```
printf("%ld\n", 10000*10000);
```

I get the output as `100000000`.

Can the format specifier `%ld` also cause type-casting or the behaviour is undefined? I was expecting to get some garbage value (loop-over from max value) as max value of int is +32767.

And whatever happens in the above statement, doesn't happen for the following statement,

```
printf("%f\n", 5/2); //probably 5 is double ?? If yes, how's the result justified
```

The output is : `-0.109126`. Why?

Comment: "max value of int is +32767"...not on most platforms!

Comment: The max value of an integer is dependent on your compiler, in most (all?) 32 bit systems an int is 32 bits, not 16.

Comment: @Jim Lewis On hundreds of millions of embedded processors per year : `INT_MAX == 32767`.  It is common.  C is very popular on these devices.

Comment: With few exceptions, if the format specifier and argument are not in type agreement, the result is UB.

Comment: @chux clearly Insane Coder is not on one of these.

Comment: @MK. The attributes of the post, comments and answers and not the OP are most relevant.  [SO model: Focus on the post, not the person.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case:

```
printf("%ld\n", 10000*10000);
```

The literal `10000` is an `int`.  On most systems, `int` is at least 32-bit.  So `10000*10000` evaluates to `100000000`, also an `int`.  `printf` however it looking for a `long int`.  So this is undefined behavior, regardless of the fact that you got the expected result.

In this case:

```
printf("%f\n", 5/2);
```

The literals `5` and `2` are of type `int`, so integer division is performed and the resulting value `2` is also of type `int`.  `printf` then attempts to read this `int` value as a `float`, resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: "reads this value and casts it up to `long int`"  -> No.  This is UB as specifier and type do not match.

Comment: @chux Are you sure?  gcc with -Wall -Wextra doesn't give a warning for `int x=5; printf("%ld\n",x);` but does for `long x=5; printf("%d\n",x);`

Comment: Yes sure.  It "works" because your `long` and `int` are the same size.  Try it with a platform wtih a 16-bit `int`.  My gcc with 32-`int` and -Wformat gives warnings for both.

Comment: @chux I stand corrected.  I have 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long` and gcc did warn in both directions.  I must have missed that.  And now that I think about it, it makes sense that `printf` should be reading exactly the correct number of bytes.

Comment: Minor point: "On most systems, `int` is at least 32-bit".  An oft quoted statistic, but rarely back-up with evidence.  My rough estimate is that `int` as 32-bit` occurs 2/3 of the time.  There are lots of itty-bitty machines out there.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%f\n", 5/2);
```

`5/2` result is `2`(an `int`) .It is read using `%f` , thus invoking *UB* .

If you want correct result try this -

```
printf("%f\n", (double)5/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

To have your max value of int just do :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
main()
{
  printf("The maximum value of INT = %d\n", INT_MAX);
}
```

Result for me :

```
The maximum value of INT = 2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `printf("%ld\n", 10000*10000);` is UB as `"%ld"` expects to match a `long` and `10000*10000` is not a `long`, but an `int`.
2. "Can the format specifier %ld also cause type-casting" --> No
3. "Can the format specifier %ld also cause behavior is undefined?" With few exceptions (*), the specifier and argument must match in type.  Recall arguments in a variadic function go through usual promotions like `short` to `int`.
4. The *minimum* value of `INT_MAX` is 32767.  It is often 2147483647.
5. `printf("%f\n", 5/2);` is UB as `"%f"` expects a `double` and `5/2` is an `int`.

(*) Somewhere, I think there is exception for `"%d"` to match `unsigned` and `"%x"` to match `int`.  But cannot find it for verification.